# StructureMap - Re-use instance in constructor

Tags: c#, structuremap

Supose I have the next clases:

```
public class DBUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork { ... }

public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    public CustomerRepository(DBUnitOfWork unitOfWork) { ... }
}

public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    public OrderRepository(DBUnitOfWork unitOfWork) { ... }
}

public class AppService : IAppService
{
    public AppService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ICustomerRepository customers, IOrderRepository orders) { ... }
}

public class AppView
{
    public AppView(IAppService appService) { ... }
}
```

I want to create an instance of AppView through StructureMap, that gets injected a new AppService object every time it is created, and that the AppService has the same instance of `DBUnitOfWork` for itself, and both repositories. How can I set up that on StructureMap?

**UPDATE:** I am looking for something like [this](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2008/09/25/using-structuremap-2-5-to-inject-your-entity-objects-into-services/), but fully defined in the containers configuration or through a registry.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on scope. For example you can use

```
x.For<IUnitOfWork>()
  .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
  .Use<DbUnitOfWork>();
```

There are other scope options as well. [More info here](http://ignipro.blogspot.com/2012/09/structuremap-scopes-and-life-cycles.html).

Comment: Thanks @mxmissile. I'm using it in a Windows Application, and want to create an AppView Instance for every form. I think the scope is whitin the form itself, but I don't know how to limit the scope to it.